# Postcss moderate vulnerability in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli, node-modules, postcss

I'm working on an Angular project, I did `npm i` and a moderate vulnerability postcss appeared. I did `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force`, but that doesn't work. I tried to update the dependencies and didn't work either.

When I run `npm audit`, this report appears:

[error vulnerability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/excGM.png)

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Did the npm audit fix fail to update packages, or did your application stop working? The error screenshot indicates a breaking change (new version not compatible with other things).

Comment: npm audit fix failed

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
Adding below lines in package.json and running npm update worked for me.

"overrides": {
"postcss":"^8.4.31"
}

Please note that I'm working on Angular 13 and was getting vulnerability for @angular-devkit/build-angular

Answer (score -2):

The issue is because of using the @angular-devkit/build-angular in your package.json which is internally using postcss on package-lock.json and postcss from 7.0.0 and before 8.2.10 are vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service during source map parsing so please upgrade to version 8.2.10 or later to fix this issue.

Comment: How can I upgrade that?

Comment: Change the version in package.json for the library and run npm install will upgrade.